# .NET 4.0 Excel Interop issues with dynamic collections

Tags: .net, excel, .net-4.0, excel-interop

In Excel you can return a dynamic array `System.Object[*]`, from a series object using `XValues`. In .NET 3.5 you can access the elements in this object by casting it to and array, i.e.:

```
var values = (Array)series.XValues;
```

In .NET 4.0, this no longer works, and the message

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[*]' to type 'System.Object[]'"

is given.

Any ideas? The following doesn't work:

- Casting it as dynamic.
- Casting it to a `System.Object[*]`.
- Just placing the object in a for each loop.
- Trying to access the value directly using `values[1]`, neither when cast as a dynamic.

The values inside the array do show up in the debugger however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two distinct kind of arrays in .NET, a one dimensional 'vector' and multidimensional arrays.  You got the latter back, a multidimensional array with a rank of 1.  This will happen if the unmanaged code has returned a SAFEARRAY whose lower-bound isn't 0.

You can read the content of the array with Array.GetValue().  Or convert it, like this:

```
    private static object[] ConvertArray(Array arr) {
        int lb = arr.GetLowerBound(0);
        var ret = new object[arr.GetUpperBound(0) - lb + 1];
        for (int ix = 0; ix < ret.Length; ++ix) {
            ret[ix] = arr.GetValue(ix + lb);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Test:

```
    var native = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new int[] { 42 }, new int[] { 1 });
    var dotnet = ConvertArray(native);
```

---

NOTE: you may have a problem in .NET 4.0 and up when you some COM type libraries, Office in particular.  The property or method may return a variant that contains an array.  Ends up as *dynamic* in your C# program.  The C# compiler does not generate the proper binder code in that case.  Work around that by casting first to (object), then to (Array).

Comment: The issue I have is not getting the value outside of an Array object whose lower-bound isnt 0, the issue I'm having is I am unable to convert the COM object collection into anything usable by .NET. The example code you provided involves using an object of type Array, but I am unable to cast the collection I am given to an Array.

Thanks for your time however.

Comment: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[*]`.  That's an array.

Comment: @HansPassant the difficulty is in casting to that, see link in my answer for details.

Answer (score 7):

The answer above is useful but does not address the issue of how to cast to Array.

Under .Net versions before 4.0 a simple cast would work.

in C# 4.0 one must use

```
System.Array a = (System.Array)((object)  returnedObject ); // note order of brackets
```

see
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2010/06/01/oh-that-mysteriously-broken-visiblesliceritemslist.aspx