# How to unbox a System.Int32[*] array

Tags: c#, firebird

Firebird rdr.Read() returns, for fb array columns, an object witch is in my case System.Int32[*] (non-zero based array of ints), how do I unbox it into something sane?
Connector does not have any rdr.GetZeroBasedArray() or rdr.GetUsableArray() method.

Thx in advance...

Comment: Arrays are reference types, and hence are not boxed.

Comment: Conversion code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807968/net-4-0-excel-interop-issues-with-dynamic-collections/4808751#4808751

Answer (score 4):

C# has no support for `[*]`-style (non-zero-based one-dimensional) arrays. Trying to cast to `int[]` will throw an exception.

The only option you have is to cast to `System.Array` and then use these methods to modify it:

- [`Array.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getvalue.aspx) instead of `array[i]`
- [`Array.SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.setvalue.aspx) instead of `array[i] = x;`

Alternatively, of course, you can always use `Array.GetLength` to find the length of the array, instantiate a standard `int[]` of the same length, and then use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) to copy the data over. Then you can use `array[i]` normally, but be aware that you are now operating on a separate copy.

P.S. As already pointed out, *unbox* is the wrong word. Boxing/unboxing is used only with value types, but arrays are always reference types (even arrays of value types are reference types). What you are looking for is called a *cast*. The `Array` variable will contain a reference to the same object as the `object` variable.