# Converting BSTR to String[]

Tags: c#, vba, com, vsto, bstr

I can see a number of google results for converting string array to BSTR, but none that does it the other way around. How do I do that?

### Details

I'm using VSTO + C# for writing a Word add-in. One of the functions of Word Object Model named `SynonymInfo.get_SynonymList()` appears to return a strange data type that I cannot iterate over (`foreach` fails). There is no way of getting the upper bound or length of the array either. People use this function in VBA with `UBound()`, which unfortunately isn't there in C#. I searched further and found that the data type of this function is BSTR.

The function itself is defined as `dynamic` in VSTO, so I can't really see what members are there in it. Even the QuickWatch window doesn't show any members, even though it can successfully list down the array elements.

Comment: It is not a BSTR, it returns an array.   The usual problem is that it is an array whose first index is 1 instead of 0.  Cast it to (Array).  Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4808751/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant:-  '(Array)SynoList' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'."

Comment: @HansPassant: [A CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3388/Creating-a-Dictionary-using-Word-Automation-and-Te) says that `Note on COleVariant: The COleVariant is just a wrapper MFC class for the VARIANT type. Also please note that the GetSynonymList() method returns a VARIANT, that contains a safearray of type BSTR.`

Comment: It is exactly like I predicted.  You must cast to System.Array, not string[].

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for the input. Although it didn't work right away (`(Array)SynoList` fails as I mentioned in my last comment), doing it like `(Array)(Object)SynoList` did the trick.